# Как правильно построить фразу?1

Tags: стилистика

Подслушивал кого-то  *под/за/из-за*  двер*ью/ями/ей*.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Допустимы самые разные варианты, какой лучше подойдёт - зависит от контекста и общего стиля.

Подслушивал (*находясь где*) за дверью, за дверями, у двери, у дверей (если двустворчатые).

Подслушивал (*откуда, с какой позиции* "улавливал звуки") из-за дверей, из-за двери; (*каким образом*) через дверь.

Менее вероятна ситуация, к которой подошло бы "под дверью", "из-под двери" (лёжа и приложив ухо к щели между дверью и полом, либо дверь расположена высоко - над ступеньками и т.п.).